# Python and CSV with formulae

Tags: python, excel, csv, formula

I have a CSV file with formulae, like this:

```
1;;2.74;0
=A1+C1;=A2;=C1
```

What's the best way to convert formulae into numbers, as follows

```
1;;2.74;0
3.74;3.74;2.74
```

?

The only way I know is to read it with `csv.reader` as a list of lists and then loop through each element. But it seems there must be a simpler way.

P. S. I have a hint to use `eval`

Comment: A general answer to the question seems not to be very simple, because to obtain result for `=A2`, you have first to calculate `=A1+C1`.

Comment: "P. S. I have a hint to use `eval`" -> unless this is homework, that is not good practice.   Use a package like openpyxl that can parse spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1):

The CSV format does not support formulas. It is a plain text only format.
Although some popular software like MS Excel, will calculate the formulas. I am not aware of a parser that allows this. You may however, attempt to write your own parser. The success of this will depend on how advanced formulas you are looking to have in the CSV.